# NSTextView extremely sluggish

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nstextview

I'm using NSTextView controls in my app for capturing free format richt text. These controls are all bound to attributes of Core Data entities (attributes are of type NSData).

The behaviour of text editing inside NSTextView feels extremely sluggish: characters appearance is lagging behind keyboard entry.

I have unchecked all things that could remotely impact performance, like spell checking, grammar checking etc. All to no avail. The sluggishness disappears when I remove the binding so I suspect there's something going on there but I can't figure out what.

Any suggestions?

EDIT - Some more background info: Core Data store used is an XML store but that is only for development purposes. The deployment target is sqlite. The rich text is stored within the Core Data store, so not stored externally.

EDIT 2 - I found that removing the "Undo" feature on NSTextView improves the responsiveness quite effectively. However, if that's the remedy, I would be truly disappointed as that is generally considered an important feature when editing texts.

Comment: How much text are you editing? Is AutoSaving turned on? If not, how often are you saving the store?

Comment: Depends. From a couple of lines (max 30 words) to bigger texts. It's always sluggish, no matter the size of the text. I'm not too sure about AutoSaving. I actually was not aware of this feature... Is it something I configure with my persistent document class?

Comment: Does your binding have "Continuously Updates Value" checked? If so, that's going to be a major performance drag, as it means that its doing a ton of work for you on every key press. You probably want that to be unchecked which will let the editing protocols do their work. (Also note, you'll want to be binding to an NS*Controller and not directly to your model for those editing things to work right.)

Comment: Nope it doesn't. I recently upgraded to Xcode 4.2 and it seems to have disappeared. Mystery...